# No carrier on Marvell Yukon 88E8057 based on-board Ethernet (20.04+)

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

Greets. Trying to install Ubuntu 20.04.3 on a Shuttle SX58J3 computer. This is a Intel X58 + ICH10R based Core i7 box with two Marvell Yukon 88E8057 on-board Ethernet ports.

They're detected OK, the sky2 module is loaded as expected but whatever I try, the interface remains in the NO-CARRIER state.
Yes, the cable and switch port are OK. I've tried loading Windows 10 on that same box and network worked flawlessly.
Yes, I've tried playing with every option the sky2 module has to no avail.
Yes, I've tried taking the interface down and up and it didn't work for me unlike for another person who posted here about a similar situation.
I've tried every Ubuntu version, from 20.04 to 22.04 night builds: same.
I've tried playing with the autoneg and speed settings in ethtool: nothing.

I'm really running out of ideas. For the moment, I've resorted to adding an Intel-based Ethernet PCI-E controller.

It might be worth nothing that the Ethernet port does goes up and stay up while the machine is in the BIOS startup sequence. The light goes off right after the kernel is started.

Very grateful of any help. Should I file a bug?

Comment: OK, my bad. It works fine with the HWE kernel. I could swear that I had tried, but obviously I hadn't.
Strange that it doesn't work with 21.10 though.

Comment: Alain, you can post an answer to your question. Please read this: https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer